# SetError в TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как исправить, чтобы буква Е не обрезалась в слове Error ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/emailView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="6"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
   >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegistration"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Регистрация"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAuthorization"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Авторизация"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @iFr0z Есть варианты решения проблемы ?

Comment: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` для `emailView`

Comment: @iFr0z не помогает

Comment: скинь весь `xml`

Comment: @iFr0z Добавил фото той части, которая почему-то не доабвилась